# Making a greeting program in python

Tags: python

Really easy stuff, sorry in advance for the idiotic question but I'm just not understanding how to do this... I want to make a function that asks the user's name and then greets the user by name.

so if I were to do greet(yo)...
What's your name? Tom
Yo, Tom

I've got this so far:

```
def greet(yo):
    print("Whats your name")
    raw_input(name)
    return yo + name
```

Comment: Change `raw_input(name)` to `name = raw_input()`. And you might want to change `return` to `print`

Comment: There are many good programming tutorials (and books) for Python; maybe read at least one from start to end. If you feel you lack the patience for it, programming is not the right thing for you, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 2):

Save the return value from `raw_input` into a variable:

```
def greet(yo):
    name = raw_input("What's your name: ")
    return yo + name
print greet("hi! ")
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> greet('hi! ')
What's your name: Tom
'hi! Tom'
```

Answer (score 0):

For python 2, use `raw_input` to get input.

For python 3, use `input` to get input.

```
def greet(greeting):
    name = raw_input("Hi, whats your name?") #python 2
    return greeting + name

print greet("Hi, ")
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Python program that asks the user to enter their name, and then greet them. 

name = input("Hello, What's your name?")
# Then type in your name.

print("Hello " + name+ " it's nice to meet you"+ "!")
```

## For example:

Hello, What's your name?Bob

Hello Bob it's nice to met you!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). The OP asked for a function, so one should provide a function, he can call. And code format matters in Python, so you should properly format your answer with the `{}` button.